# About perpendicularity of vectors

Tags: vectors

If we have two perpendicular vectors $A$ and $B$ on the same surface and find another vector $C$ perpendicular to that surface such that $A \cdot C = 0$, then is true that $B \cdot C = 0$, too?

Comment: If $A\cdot C=0$ is the only restriction, then let $C=B$

Comment: Suppose $C \neq B$. If that makes the answer to the question in my OP negative, then why?

Comment: Imagine $A$ and $B$ were the $x$ and $y$ axes respectively. For $C$ to be perpendicular to $A$, it can be anywhere in the $yz$-plane, which is not necessarily perpendicular to $B$.

Comment: Except $C$ is perpendicular to the *plane* spanned by $A$ and $B$, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly $B$ is perpendicular to $C$ so $B \cdot C = |B| |C| \cos \pi/2 = 0$.

Comment: Consider a plane passing through 3 points $A = (1, 1, 1)$, $B = (3, 3, 3)$, $C = (5, 5, 5)$. Our job is to find a vector orthogonal to that plane. $B - A =(2, 2, 2)$ is a vector on the plane. Let $X = (x, y, z)$ be the vector orthogonal to the plane. $X \cdot (B - A) = x + y + z = 0$. So, any solution to that equation is perpendicular to $B - A$. Does that mean that any solution to $X \cdot (B - A) = x + y + z = 0$ also perpendicular to $C - A$, for example?

Comment: In the example you give, $C-A = (4, 4, 4)$ is simply a scalar multiple of $B-A = (2, 2, 2)$, so of course that will be the case. Also, you should note that $X \cdot (B-A) = 2x + 2y + 2z$.

Comment: Then let $A = (1, 2, -1), B = (-1, 1, 4), C = (1, 3, -2)$. $X \cdot (B - A) = -2x - y + 5z = 0$. Does that mean a solution to the equation is also perpendicular to, say, $C - A$? Thanks.

Comment: $X\cdot (C-A) = y-z$. Certainly there are situations where $-2x-y+5z = 0$ but $y-z \neq 0$, and vice versa.